# Go with Application Insights

Tags: go, azure-application-insights

I use `github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go` package to communicate with Azure Application Insights and I want to gather logs from logrus (logging package) and http request logs from gin (http server package).
I managed to send both logs to AI as one of answers [there](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/issues/25) presents.

The only problem is with sending these logs, because sometimes it lasts 3 minutes and sometimes around 15. Is this a problem with AI or Telemetries should be flushed somehow?

I also tried reducing max batch size and interval by

```
telemetryConfig := appinsights.NewTelemetryConfiguration(c.InstrumentationKey)
telemetryConfig.MaxBatchSize = 128 //default is 1024
telemetryConfig.MaxBatchInterval = 1 * time.Second //default is 10
```

and then creating a client

```
appinsights.NewTelemetryClient(telemetryConfig)
```

but it's still not close to second-like time.

performing `Flush()` on client channel does not work too.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: *...because sometimes it lasts 3 minutes and sometimes around 15...* -> you mean before you can see the data in the portal? Because yes, the processing of the data can be delayed for up to a few minutes. It is not meant to be a (near) realtime logging solution.

Comment: Yes, it was what I meant. The problem is I have an error in my Azure CD Pipeline because it's tested if application have any logs in AI and I'm not allowed to change that. But if it's not problem from my side it's not that bad. Thanks